# Can i filter with a loop in ag grid

Tags: ag-grid

I need help with a filter instance ,I want to filter from pairs in an array that have a sum of 90 .I tried the code below but it did not work.

```
export class FilterComponent implements OnInit {
private i; 
private r; 
private indx;

 constructor() { }

 ngOnInit() {

 }

filterInPairs(){
for(this.i =1; this.i<=89; this.i++)//I'm trying to print 1.......89
for(this.r =89; this.r>0; this.r--)//print 89....1 in descending order

//console.log(this.i) works perfect
//console.log(this.r) works

for(this.indx =0; this.indx <89; this.indx ++) //increase by 1 till 

this.gridApi.setQuickFilter(i[this.indx],r[this.indx]);
//I am expecting an output like {1,89},{2,88},{3,87}......but I did't get anything
}
}
```

Comment: What does "did not work" mean? Wrong result or an error message?

Comment: The error I get is